# Slick PostgreSQL Integration

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, lagom, slick-pg

I'm new to scala and I'm trying to integrate a PostgreSQL database to a Lagom application written in scala.I'm trying to utilise the persistence API of Lagom. Lagom has inbuilt support for slick.

My table has 3 fields id of type int, name of type string, data of type jsonb

Since Slick doesn't support json format I'm trying to use [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) .

Below is my implementation

My custom profile class

```
import com.github.tminglei.slickpg.{ExPostgresProfile, PgPlayJsonSupport}
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
import slick.basic.Capability
import slick.jdbc.{JdbcCapabilities, PostgresProfile}

trait CustomPostgresProfile extends ExPostgresProfile with PgPlayJsonSupport {
  def pgjson = "jsonb"

  override protected def computeCapabilities: Set[Capability] =
    super.computeCapabilities + JdbcCapabilities.insertOrUpdate

  override val api = PostgresJsonSupportAPI

  object PostgresJsonSupportAPI extends API with JsonImplicits {}
}

object CustomPostgresProfile extends PostgresProfile
```

My table definition

```
import com.custom.persistence.profile.CustomPostgresProfile.api._
import play.api.libs.json._


case class CustomDataEntity(id:int,name: String, data: JsValue)

object CustomDataTableDef {
  val data = TableQuery[CustomDataTableDef]
}
class CustomDataTableDef(tag: Tag) extends Table[CustomDataEntity](tag, "custom"){
  

  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)

  def name = column[String]("name")
  def data = column[JsValue]("data")

  override def * =
    (id,name,data) <> (CustomDataEntity.tupled,CustomDataEntity.unapply(_))

}
```

when I'm trying to compile the code, I get the below 2 errors

```
could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
[error]   def data = column[JsValue]("data")

Cannot resolve symbol <>
```

Please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `object CustomPostgresProfile` extends `PostgresProfile` instead of `CustomPostgresProfile`. If you fix that, it works.